# Azure bearer token lifetime

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, bearer-token

I have a python code to call a graph API and browse directory on sharepoint. The directory has 120GB of files and needs hours to scan. However, what I have observed is the script just shows as running on Visual Studio code and no further execution happens. I am printing the files names in the loop and it stops to put the file names after an hour.

Can it be because of Token getting expired after an hour? If yes, why I do not get an error stating the token to be invalid?

```
# Define imports
import requests

# Copy access_token and specify the MS Graph API endpoint you want to call, e.g. 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups' to get all groups in your organization
#access_token = '{ACCESS TOKEN YOU ACQUIRED PREVIOUSLY}'

url = "[URL TO THE SHAREPOINT]"
headers = {
  'Authorization': access_token
}

consentfilecount=0
clientreportcount = 0
graphlinkcount = 0

while True:#
    #print(graph_result.json()['@odata.nextLink'])
    graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    if ('value' in graph_result.json()):
      for list in graph_result.json()['value']:
        if(("Client Consent Form").lower() in list["name"].lower()):
            consentfilecount +=1
            print(list["name"])
        if(("Final Client Report").lower() in list["name"].lower()):
            clientreportcount +=1
            print(list["name"])
        #print(graph_result.json())
      if('@odata.nextLink' in graph_result.json()):
        url = graph_result.json()['@odata.nextLink']
        graphlinkcount += 1
      else:
        break

print(consentfilecount)
```

Comment: "*Can it be because of Token getting expired after an hour? If yes, why I do not get an error stating the token to be invalid?*" It most certainly *could* be, and it's a good place to start your debugging. However it is impossible to answer this question affirmatively as you've asked it since you haven't provided a [mre] of how you're implementing this.

Comment: "*I am printing the files names and that is how I am putting the above statement.*" I may be missing something, but I don't think this sentence makes sense as written - do you mind clarifying it?

Comment: Added the code that I am trying to use. Edited the original post as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can it be because of Token getting expired after an hour?

The behavior you describe is almost certainly due to the fact that the bearer token you seem to be using is indeed valid only for an hour or so.

> If yes, why I do not get an error stating the token to be invalid?

By default, [`requests` does not raise exceptions based solely on HTTP status codes](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#errors-and-exceptions) to allow developers to choose how they want to handle such scenarios. In your case, your `while True:` loop simply continues running, successfully parsing the JSON structure that comes back from the error response but never actually hitting any of your conditions within the block.

If you do want your script to throw an exception on non-successful HTTP response codes, you can add a call to [`raise_for_status()`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status):

```
graph_result = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
graph_result.raise_for_status()
```

However if your code is expected to normally run for periods in excess of your token's validity, you should probably work the proper OAuth refresh flows into your code to prevent such errors from occurring.

Comment: Any direction of how do I achieve OAuth refresh flows?

Comment: @WhoamI Microsoft has [a slew of documentation about their OAuth implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts), including [a specific document about Tokens (including refresh tokens)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/security-tokens), have you reviewed any of it? They also have [a robust Python SDK for Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python) which includes several lovely abstractions for handling these auth patterns. There's also a bunch of questions on this very site asking the same question which could be useful too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the default lifetime of an Access Token for Microsoft Graph [is between 60 and 90 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configurable-token-lifetimes#token-lifetime-policies-for-access-saml-and-id-tokens) so for longrunning tasks you should check if it's expiring and refresh it in time (or handle the error accordingly).